# "Cost" vs "expense" -- a usage question

Tags: meaning, word-choice, differences

While editing some ad copy, and I was given the sentence, "Defending a lawsuit can be a big *cost* for your business." (My italics.)

I keep thinking the proper word to use is "expense" rather than "cost" as in: "Defending a lawsuit can be a big *expense* for your business." But I'm just not sure I'm correct.

Can anyone help with more definitive guidance? Can "cost" and "expense" be used interchangeably in a sentence like this?

Thank you!

Comment: They are synonymous, though [cost](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/cost) is defined as: *Law* Charges incurred in bringing litigation, including court fees and charges that may be payable by the losing party... etc. However, since defending a lawsuit is already given, expense sounds better to me (but that's just an opinion.)

Comment: @medica We are straying into legal definitions that are complicated, since *costs* and *expenses* are legally defined terms that are different in many circumstances, and even different locales within the US. The stenographer's fees for a deposition are costs, but the lawyer's time is *expenses*. A minefield.

Answer (score 4):

The noun cost could include more than money to be spent such as human resources (personnel who could work for other constructive things without the lawsuit), losing business to a competitor (business that can be generated without the lawsuit), etc. which are not easily and accurately **monetized**.

We call "*the loss of other alternatives when one alternative is chosen*" **opportunity cost**, not **opportunity expense** as it can't be monetized as easily as other expenses.

When you describe monthly living expenses, *expenses* is more idiomatic than *cost* as it could be monetized (almost exactly per month).

They could be used interchangeably depending on context, but the key difference is whether it could be monetized or not.

"Cost of living" is more idiomatic than "expense of living" because it is not easy to monetize it exactly.

In your context, *cost* is more idiomatic because it includes other things that cannot be monetized. It doesn't necessarily mean that you can't use *cost* for things that could be monetized.

Answer (score 3):

First, a disclaimer: this is not legal advice. It's just a discussion about the English Language and its Usage.

The words *cost* and *expense* are synonyms, but phrases like *can be a big expense* are normally used in the narrow sense of the amount of money to be spent. The parallel construction *can be a big cost*, however, is commonly construed more broadly to include negative impacts to reputation, time, relationships, etc. (as well as money).

> **Expense** *noun*
> 1 The cost incurred in or required for something
> [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/expense)
>
> **Cost** *noun*
> 1.1 The effort, loss, or sacrifice necessary to achieve or obtain something
> [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/cost)

Answer (score 1):

The difference between cost and expense is also usually related to magnitude. Expenses are usually money-related, while cost may not be. You'll see the word "cost" in phrases where "expense" wouldn't make sense:

> They lost the game; that was the *cost* of the penalty.
>
> The *cost* of living won't leave much of my paycheck.

There's no hard and fast rule about when you should switch from expense to cost in terms of monetary amounts (one person's expense is another's cost), but cost implies additional losses besides just money, and is appropriate when you're suggesting that more than just money is at stake, such as livelihood, possessions, or even life itself.

Comment: Very nice answer, but *the expense of time and energy* is not uncommon.

Answer (score 0):

Suspecting that there must be some arcane distinction between **cost** and **expense** in the legal and accounting fields, I betook myself to a quick "go to" resource for legal stuff, [US Legal.com](http://uslegal.com).

Their definition of **cost** is highly detailed.  A snippet:

> The expenses of a suit or action which may be recovered by law from the losing party. Such allowable costs are often defined by statute or by a court's rules, and, under the American Rule, in most cases they do not include attorney fees. Court costs usually include: filing fees, charges for serving summons and subpoenas, court reporter charges for depositions, court transcripts and copying papers and exhibits....

One can infer from the definition of **costs** that **expenses** is indeed synonymous for practical purposes. Interestingly, under the so-called American Rule "costs" are normally recoverable, while other monies expended in pursuit of a legal action - expenses? - may not be.

The legal eagles continue:

> Costs are the necessary expenditures that must be made in order to run a business. Every factor of production has an associated cost.

Once again, **costs** are defined in terms of **expenditures**, which are close enough kin to **expenses** in my book.

I'd say if you need a legal our accounting ruling on this, call your lawyer or accountant.  Otherwise, the EL&U answer could well be that the words are synonyms.

Answer (score 0):

Either word is okay; however, *business expense* is a familiar phrase. (One refers to claiming tax deductions as *business expenses*, not *business costs*.) So I'd go with *expense*. It also sounds more sophisticated.

Answer (score 0):

> Defending a lawsuit can be a big cost for your business.

The sentence ought to be judged from the standpoint of reader, not the advertiser. I think this is where the hitch comes from. The court cost is a business expense.

*Cost* as used by business is an expense that directly relates to productive activity, such as inventory, material or labor. Costs are inherent to the business activity. Taxes and fees are unavoidable. Otherwise, *expense* is used - as in legal expense or entertainment expense. Expenses are discretionary, at least in theory.

There are common derived accounting terms that involve one class but not the others.

> Gross margin is the difference between revenue and cost of goods sold, or COGS, divided by revenue, expressed as a percentage. Generally, it is calculated as the selling price of an item, less the cost of goods sold (production or acquisition costs, essentially).

This is the key idea behind the distinction used by business.

So it might sound just fine to a law firm's PR person, but it's not OK to a businessperson.